# How to install IE9 when KB2120976 is not applicable to my Windows 7 x86 Ultimate edition?

Tags: windows-7, installation, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to install IE9, visit http://beautyoftheweb.com, download it and then says it's downloading prereqs.

After a minute, the installer says there's a problem and directs me to [Prerequisites for installing Internet Explorer 9 Beta](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2399238.)

I click on the x86 installers one by one... most say "already installed"..

But http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2120976/ says "The update is not applicable to your computer". Lame.

So I try the IE9 install and the go through the whole process again with the same result.

I discovered there's an IE9 install log at C:\Windows\IE9_main.log which logs the install process and reports an Error for 2120976

```
 00:06.630: ERROR:   Error installing
 prerequisite file
(C:\Users\Vijay\AppData\Local\Temp\IE98036.tmp\KB2120976_x86.msu):
 0x80240017 (2149842967) 00:06.677:
 INFO:    PauseOrResumeAUThread:
 Successfully resumed Automatic
 Updates. 00:12.090: INFO:    Link
 clicked, opening URL in new
 window:'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=185111'
 00:12.106: INFO:    Setup exit code:
 0x00009C47 (40007) - Required updates
 are missing from the system.are
 missing from the system.
```

Any idea why KB2120976 is inapplicable to my LEGAL Windows 7 Ultimate system?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I never figured this out... And ended up building a new more modern machine with a modern graphics card. This new machine kix butt and doesn't have any issues running IE9 -- W00t!

Answer (score 1):

Go here, this is the correct package

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4331306E-0F40-4E4C-8A26-66547BB81AEA

.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's the link I download from the kb article, but still receive the same error.

Comment: You sure your W7 is x86 and not x64? Here is the one for x64...http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=031f7c21-fb6a-4f6c-86ff-6ac1baa640df&displaylang=en

Comment: Yep, I'm definitely x86 and not x64

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already installing beta software you can try installing beta of sp1 then ie9, thats what I did no issues.